# Secure react routing with spring security

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-security, jwt

I introduced in my projects log in/out via spring security and jwt auth. At the moment I would like to prevent unauthorized user to enter the routs like /admin. Should I make a call before making history.push("/admin") and check the response to determine if user should see it or not?

How to prevent the accessing routes? I do not mean making api calls...

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Store the login status of the user in react state or global state if you are using redux.

Then you can make a private route in react and check the user roles

```
const PrivateRoute = (props)=>(
  <Route {...props.routeProps} render={() => (
    props.logged_in===true ? (
        <div>{props.children}</div>
        ) : (
        <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/',
            state: { from: props.location }
        }} /> )
    )} />
)
```

and you can use this component like

```
<PrivateRoute path = {"/admin/"} ><Dashboard /></PrivateRoute>
```

Comment: is it safe? I guess you can easily access the state via React dev tools?

Comment: No code is safe in client side. you have to protect your code by using firebase or some other ways